# Flexbuilder won't launch...arrrgh!

Tags: actionscript-3, crash, flexbuilder

In a panic since I'm trying to meet  a deadline so appreciate any feedback on this.
For some reason, Flexbuilder 3 on my mac won't launch, crashes on startup.
I've never experienced this before.

Checked the .log file and what seems to be the problem is the following

/Users/foo/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#Security/FlashPlayerTrust/flexbuilder.fbr (No such file or directory)

WTF is the flexbuilder.fbr???

Googled but not much luck.

The only thing I've done that might have caused this is change flash player versions system wide using the official flash player uninstaller...but obviously this should not happen

Any feedback appreciated...

Comment: the only thing I found on google was someone with the same issue...but no answer
http://groups.google.com.tw/group/macromedia.flex.general_discussion/browse_thread/thread/eb1ff3a81ea7ca3f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know where it went, but this file just contains a number of paths of 'trusted' locations for the Flash Player. Normally when you create a new workspace in FlexBuilder it adds the workspace location to this file, or if you create a project outside of the workspace it adds the project path.

It's surprising the absence of that file would keep FlashBuilder from launching though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my workaround was to simply create an empty text file called flexbuilder.fbr in the location of the missing file.

But still would like to know the purpose of this file and how it went MIA...